# How to set scp_if_ssh = True for a group?

Tags: ansible

It's simple to set this variable in an ansible.cfg but it makes sense only for hosts that do not have sftp (and most likely python as well). So I have a group for routers – is it possible to set this variable in group_vars?

Comment: My understanding from the documentation is that you cannot; but did you try as explained in http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#group-variables?

Comment: Tried this:

    `[routers:vars]`
       `scp_if_ssh = True`
       `ansible_scp_if_ssh = True`
    
Doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure about group vars but you can set that option from the inventory file via `ansible_ssh_transfer_method=scp`.
Might also work for group vars.
Checked with version 2.3 of Ansible.

Comment: Where did you get this name from?

Comment: I got it from the source code

Comment: Possible values `smart|sftp|scp|piped`